# Dos Script(BAT) - Print Directory path only when it match certain pattern

Tags: dos, design-patterns, directory, match

I am very new to Dos Script, however I have a task on hand which I believe will be most efficient to execute in Dos Scipt(.BAT).

I will run this BAT file in Window XP Professional

Currently I have a Drive let's say B: Drive which consists of 30 folders and 100,000+ sub folders(not files)

Within the drive there are more than ten thousand job folder and each with a job number

I need to print out a list of all folders that consist of a job number

The job number pattern 
(imagine the job number is A1234567 with the first char always an alphabet and the follow by 6 - 7 numeric character then a space and the job name

e.g B:/Lv1/Lv2/A1234567 xxxxx/Lv4/Lv5/xxx.xls

Unfortunately this job number maybe in different level

e.g B:/Lv1/Lv2/A1234567 xxxxx/Lv4/Lv5/xxx.xls

e.g B:/Lv1/B5678214 xxxxx/Lv3/Lv4/xxx.xls

e.g B:/Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/Lv4/Z0425673 xxxxx/Lv5/Lv6/xxx.doc

Lets say if we start from the top and once the sciprt find the job number, it wont continue to drill down to another level from that folder.

So the outcome will be like this

e.g B:/Lv1/Lv2/A1234567 xxxxx

e.g B:/Lv1/B5678214 xxxxx

e.g B:/Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/Lv4/Z0425673 xxxxx

Comment: First things first. _Is_ this DOS (as in MSDOS with its brain dead BAT language) or is this `cmd.exe`, the command prompt under Windows with a slightly less brain-dead CMD language?

Comment: I am trying to write it in BAT language, thanks

Comment: Let mer rephrase that: *Is* this DOS (as in MSDOS with its brain dead BAT language) or is this `cmd.exe`, the command prompt under Windows with a slightly less brain-dead CMD language?  Both support BAT, but the available commands in CMD are much richer and much more abundant than in DOS. So, which OS (Operating System, like Windows <version>, DOS <version> or iOS <version> or Linux <type> <version>) should this BAT run under.

Comment: Thanks Golez I will execute the BAT file in Window XP Professional, hope this answer your question.

Comment: Do you only need the paths to job number directories with files in their tree?

Comment: 'brain dead' DOS eh?....Hmmm... in answer to your question, check out the tags!! Oh, and where (s)he states "I will run this BAT file in Window XP Professional" it seems to narrow it right down somewhat, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

e.g B:\Lv1\Lv2\A1234567 xxxxx\Lv4\Lv5\xxx.xls

instead of:

e.g B:/Lv1/Lv2/A1234567 xxxxx/Lv4/Lv5/xxx.xls